# jetty get webapp list

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I need to get some server properties from server to my servlet in init method, **before** any request execute(in init method). Actually I neet get list on all working on this server connectors, all working webapps and, most important, - port numbers or connectors. 
Desired jetty version - up to 8 version including.

So I need something like `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`, but not for embdeded, but from existing server, on wich my servlet is running.
This information shuld be on jetty as far as webapp deployer operating with this info. But I can't find where.

Answer (score 5):

Enabling JMX in Jetty's `start.ini` would allow you to use code similar to the following:

```
final MBeanServer mBeanServerConnection = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
final String[] portAttribute = new String[] {"port"};

// Jetty 9 MBeans
final ObjectName webappcontext9 = new ObjectName("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp:context=*,type=webappcontext,id=*");
final Set<ObjectName> webappcontexts9 = mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(webappcontext9, null);
for (final ObjectName objectName : webappcontexts9) {
    System.out.println(objectName.getKeyProperty("context"));
}

final ObjectName serverconnector9 = new ObjectName("org.eclipse.jetty.server:context=*,type=serverconnector,id=*");
final Set<ObjectName> serverconnectors9 = mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(serverconnector9, null);
for (final ObjectName objectName : serverconnectors9) {
    System.out.println("listening port for " + objectName.getCanonicalName() + " is " + mBeanServerConnection.getAttributes(objectName, portAttribute).asList().get(0).getValue());
}

// Jetty 8 and 7 MBeans
final ObjectName webappcontext8 = new ObjectName("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp:type=webappcontext,id=*,name=*");
final Set<ObjectName> webappcontexts8 = mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(webappcontext8, null);
for (final ObjectName objectName : webappcontexts8) {
    System.out.println(objectName.getKeyProperty("name"));
}

final ObjectName serverconnector8 = new ObjectName("org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio:type=selectchannelconnector,id=*");
final Set<ObjectName> serverconnectors8 = mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(serverconnector8, null);
for (final ObjectName objectName : serverconnectors8) {
    System.out.println("listening port for " + objectName.getCanonicalName() + " is " + mBeanServerConnection.getAttributes(objectName, portAttribute).asList().get(0).getValue());
}
```

Of course you'll need to configure Jetty to load the web application that contains this code last or it won't get the complete list of other web applications loaded.

Comment: Ok, this anwer is deserve  bounty, but i know there should be a way to get all these via Naming and Directory Interface rather than via JMX.